# Find max and min of a inner product with vector having component range

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^n $ be a variable, with constraints on each dimension/component, $v_i \in [L_i U_i]$ where $ L, U \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

On the other hand, I have a constant $C \in \mathbb{R}^n$, now my question is given $C, L, U$, how can I find the max and min of $\langle C, v \rangle$?

And if possible, the $v^*$ for both maximum and minimum?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized, each component is independent, so I can simply solve the min and max problem on $L_i, U_i$ and $C_i$, concatenate them together would do